# How to cut posts off an iron bed

Tags: tools

[image]I have a 4 poster bed that I want to shorten the two foot posts. It's hard to tell if it is iron or steel or what because it has a faux painted finish.  The other snag is I need to keep it in place because the only way to get it out of my house is to hoist it over the deck rails. There are ball caps that look like brass on each post that I would want to replace onto the shorter posts.  Any ideas?

Comment: First see if part or all of the post unscrews into sections. You might be able to just shuffle parts and reassemble. If  you absolutely must cut, a hacksaw with suitable blade will work but there will be additional  work needed to clean up the cut surface and remount the fineal caps.

Comment: A large diameter pipe cutter? wrap the posts with tape to protect it and give the pipe cutter a spin or ten...

Comment: Pictures would be really helpful.

Comment: I can't find a way to add pictures to this thread.

Comment: Just added photo

Comment: It would be easier to replace the frame rather than modify it. Once the posts are cut down, it will be nearly impossible to make it look right again. The ball finial would need to be cut off and then re-welded on. The cutting and welding operations would completely destroy the finish. You would need to sand down the entire thing and repaint it because that exact finish would be extremely difficult to replicate.

Comment: Some thick canvas for protection, a nice paint marker line and a grinder with a cutoff wheel, followed by a bit of hand filing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if you're looking to keep things clean, a pipe cutter would be the least messy.  If you want to keep tool purchases cheap, and can handle a little mess, then a hacksaw would likely work.

All that being said.  If you want to put the bed knobs back on after you're done, you might find that you have to do some welding/brazing.  If the bed knobs screw in, then there's likely a threaded insert inside the post.  Once you shorten the post, you'll have to find a way to remove and refit the insert into the shorter post.  Obviously if the knobs simply slide into the top of the post, then you won't have any trouble at all re attaching them.

Comment: Just added photo